# The order which Javascript Codes get executed

Tags: javascript

I want to figure out the order of a javascript file being executed. I have an example below. Let me know which way is the correct way.

```
//JS gets read from top to bottom:
var hello = 6; //JS sees a varaible declared, it stores variable hello in memory
hello = 4; //Then, JS sees a change to var hello, change the value of hello in the same spot of the memory
console.log(hello); //Lastly, JS sees it needs to execute this function, grabs the value of variable of hello from the memory

// OR is it like:
var hello = 6; //JS sees this is not a function, ingores
hello = 4; //JS sees this is not a function, ingores
console.log(hello); //Then JS sees it needs to execute this function, it goes back to the top of the file to look for variable hello
```

Lastly, is there any resource out there on this topic for me to dig deeper (any books? Links?). Lastly, i'm looking to master javascript, is there any advanced javascript book that you guys recommend?

Comment: What? Why should it ignore `var` declarations outside of a function? Or do you mean that the `var` declarations don’t get executed until their values are needed? That would require a lot of backtracking, so I suppose that the first way is correct. In any case, you have to understand variable declaration and function declaration hoisting as well: `var hello = 6;` is actually interpreted as `var hello; hello = 6;` where the `var hello;` is put way up at the function scope or script scope.

Answer (score 2):

It's the first way. JavaScript doesn't ignore lines and backtrack to them later. It executes them in order.

You can demonstrate this for yourself by stepping through line-by-line with a debugger and inspecting the value of `hello`.

**Edit**: As for books to recommend, Douglas Crockford's "JavaScript: The Good Parts" is a pretty great book. It hones in on which aspects of the language are useful, and establishes some pretty good coding standards and practices to adopt. There's another called "JavaScript Patterns" by Stoyan Stefanov that covers some good architectural patterns that play to the language's strengths rather than simply trying to port the Gang of Four's Design Patterns verbatim. (It's a few years old, though, so it doesn't address some of ES6 features.)

Comment: ahh. good point. let me know if you recommend advanced js books or recourses.

Comment: Certainly. I've updated my answer with some book recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is synchronous and single-threaded, which means your code will run from top to bottom as in your first example.

However, javascript often employs various webAPIs like `setTimeout` and `xhr` that provide asynchronous behavior. These will add functions to a task queue which will be handled by the event loop. For an amazing explanation of how this all works, I recommend watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ).

Comment: thanks for sharing the video